# JSON Deserialise multi level C#

Tags: c#, json

I'm serializing a multi-level json object. These are called webinars and each  contain information like below. I can access the first level with no problems. I can access the 2nd level (categories >) if I do so like webinars[webinar].categories.TimeZone etc but I can't loop through it. When I try to foreach(category in webinar) {} I get:

CS1579 C# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type because does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

What have I done wrong?

thanks for your help.

SAMPLE JSON

```
{
  "date": "2017-11-08T02:33:57Z",
  "title": "Craft, The",
  "desc": "Galeazzi's fx l rad, subs for opn fx type 3A/B/C w malunion",
  "startTime": "4:03 AM",
  "endTime": "5:46 PM",
  "categories": {
    "category": "e-learning",
    "timeZone": "Asia/Jakarta",
    "language": "English"
  }
}
```

Model

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Webinar[] Webinars { get; set; }
    public ELearning[] Elearning { get; set; }
}

public class Webinar
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public WebinarCategories Categories { get; set; }
}

public class WebinarCategories
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve

```
foreach (var webinar in root.webinars) {
     foreach (var category in webinar) {

            <button href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">@category</button>
     }
}
```

Comment: The WebinarCategories Class isn't either an Array or a List.

Comment: it doesn't work since your Categories is not type of IENumerable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is pretty simple why this won't work.

If you want to loop through the categories you have to write

```
foreach (var category in webinar.Categories)
```

Then will you get an error because `WebinarCategories` does not implement `GetEnumerator` because it does not implement `IEnumerable`. If you want to store a list of categories in your webinar the easiest way would be to change your property like this.

```
public List<WebinarCategories> Categories { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change
`public WebinarCategories Categories { get; set; }`

to 
`public List<WebinarCategories> Categories { get; set; }`

or, if you really want to
`IEnumerable<WebinarCategories> Categories { get; set; }`